# How to get HTML string

Tags: android, html, string, arraylist

I have a string which is in HTML, I want to get it and add it to my ArraryList.

```
ArrayList<Adapter> strings = new ArrayList<Adapter>();
///------------/////
////////////////////
strings.add(new Adapter("", ""));
```

The string:

```
<string name="stringg"><![CDATA[<b>Title</b><br><small>Description]]></string>
```

I tried `strings.add(new Adapter(""+R.string.stringg, ""));` but it comes a number.

Adapter code:

```
public class Adapter{
public String first;
public String last;
public Code(String first, String last) {
this.first = first;
this.last = last;
}
public static ArrayList<Adapter> getCodes() {
ArrayList<Adapter> strings = new ArrayList<Adapter>();

    strings.add(new Adapter("", ""));

return codes;
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried `getResources().getString(R.string.stringg)` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I get "The method getResources() is undefined for the type Adapter"

Comment: show Adapter` class code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as by passing Activity context in `getCodes` to access `getResources()` method:

```
public static ArrayList<Adapter> getCodes(Context mContext) {
ArrayList<Adapter> strings = new ArrayList<Adapter>();

    strings.add(new 
           Adapter(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.stringg), ""));

return codes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the belove code

```
getString(R.string.stringg)
```